# Trying to clone one disk to another but one starts up with a parition and the other doesn't

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rsync, mount

I've got an Amazon EC2 m1.small that I am trying to migrate over to t2.small.  I'm aware that because of the virtualization type being different on both types that there is no direct upgrade path.

Someone over at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=155526 suggested that I could take a snapshop of each and then create a volume from those snapshots, mount the volumes on a common server instance, remove the `/boot` folder from the `/source` system (old system) and remove the rest of the data from the new system other than `/boot` and then run: `rsync -aAXHPv /mnt/source/ /mnt/target`

Having said that I'm trying to mount each disk to perform the `rsync` and I'm running into a problem.

[Terminal Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hbCW.png)

It seems that `/dev/xvdn` (new `mnt/target`) has a partition (`dev/xvdn1`) but `dev/xvdo` does not so when I try to mount the disk `/dev/xvdn` I can't and get an error that it's already been mounted or is busy.

I think the problem is that `/dev/xvdn` is auto mounting on boot but I don't know how to stop that from happening now am I really sure that's the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If `/dev/xvdn` has a partition table, `/dev/xvdn` will not be mountable -- there's not a filesystem at the beginning of the volume to mount (there's a partition table).  At the risk of stating the obvious, try mounting `/dev/xvdn1` (the partition) instead.

Comment: I hear you about the mounting of `/dev/xvdn1`.  That does work.  Problem is I'm trying to get access to `/boot` and that doesn't seem to be available unless I directly access the disk.

Comment: Check `lsblk` to see what other partitions there are.  It may be on a partition other than 1.  With no exceptions that I can think of, mounting the volume itself,and having partitions on the volume, are always mutually exclusive, because you'd have incompatible structures that would both need to be in exactly the same place on the disk.